# DRAGGED uiview iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I'm using `SIZES CLASSES` in iOS storyboard. I want to load a `uitableview` in a uiview on simple button action.
What I'm facing is dragged view from left to right on first open. button when I click the button, it shows normal in `UIVIEW's` frame.
I also given a trailing horizontal space and leading horizontal space as shown in my image but still I'm unable to avoid the dragged `uitableview` on first load.
The `UITABLEVIEW` dragged from left to right (seems a leading space but there wasn't. I also gave both leading and trailing spaces so the the `UIVIEW` should align himself in screen's center.)

I'm calling in ViewDidLoad method `[self MYBUTTON];` to auto trigger the button and loads the `UITABLEVIEW` in `UIVIEW`. But I loads a dragged `UITABLE VIEW` but when I click on that button, It loads normally and fine.

What would I've to check and on which thing I want to focus. `SIZES CLASSES`, constraints of `UIVIEW`, or constraints of `UITABLEVIEW` or my coding.
How to solve this and what particular solution I need to handle this auto triigered `UIVIEW`?

**My CODE:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[self MYBUTTON]; // auto triigger on first load

[self.MYBUTTON addTarget:self action:@selector(myB) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

-(void)myB{
    [self unslelectallbuttons];
    self.MYBUTTON.selected = YES;
    for(UIView *subview in [self.contentView subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
    MYTABLEVIEW *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mytable"];
    vc.view.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
    [vc willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.contentView addSubview:vc.view];
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

[image: DRAGGED VIEW]

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. Can you try restating the problem?

Comment: Did the answer help?  Are you still having issues with your view's frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the order matters, but this works for me.  The tableView should appear in-place, with no evidence of being animated in from the side, as you seem to be describing.

```
[self addChildViewController:vc];
vc.view.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
[self.contentView addSubview:vc.view];
[vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

In my app, I keep a property to my tableView controller that's lazily instantiated:

```
- (BIBLESelectBookViewController *)selectBookViewController {
     if (!_selectBookViewController) {
         UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
        _selectBookViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BibleKitSelectBookViewControllerID"];

        _selectBookViewController.currentBook = self.currentBook;
    }
     return _selectBookViewController;
}
```

I'm guessing you're cycling in different tables, depending on what button is pressed.  (I use a segmented control.)  You may want to transition your view controllers instead of abruptly removing them from the container, without notification.

Here's the cycle method I'm using:

```
- (void)cycleFromViewController:(UIViewController *)firstController toViewController:(UIViewController *)secondController animateInFromRight:(BOOL)fromRight {
    // Disable segmented control interaction during the view controller transition

     self.booksChaptersVersesSegmentedControl.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    [self addChildViewController:secondController];
    [firstController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

     CGFloat offset = CGRectGetWidth(firstController.view.frame) * (fromRight ? 1 : -1);

     CGRect frame = firstController.view.frame;
     frame.origin.x += offset; // second controller animates in from right (left)
     secondController.view.frame = frame;

    [self transitionFromViewController:firstController
                      toViewController:secondController
                              duration:0.3
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                            animations:^(void) {
                                secondController.view.frame = firstController.view.frame;
                                CGRect frame = firstController.view.frame;
                                frame.origin.x -= offset; // first controller animates out to left (right)
                                 firstController.view.frame = frame;
                                [self setToolbarItems:secondController.toolbarItems animated:YES];
                                [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:self.toolbarItems ? NO : YES animated:YES];
                            }
                             completion:^(BOOL __unused finished) {
                                [firstController removeFromParentViewController];
                                [secondController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                                 self.booksChaptersVersesSegmentedControl.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                            }
     ];
}
```

Comment: It's similar to your button(s).  The selected segment specifies what view controller to display.  If you're trying to do what I'm doing, a segmented control might be easier to work with, than multiple buttons. http://i.stack.imgur.com/JQlXS.png